# ASP Table and EOF - Get error '80020009'

Tags: asp-classic

Consider a recordset containing four rows, as below

```
Team  NumDocs
OPS10 2
OPS4  1
OPS5  2
OPS7  3
```

Consider also the following row in a table to display these.

```
<td>
<% If Trim(RS("Team")) = "OPS1" And not RS.EOF Then
Response.Write(RS("NumDocs")) 
RS.MoveNext 
End If%>
</td>
<td>
<% If Trim(RS("Team")) = "OPS10" And not RS.EOF Then
Response.Write(RS("NumDocs")) 
RS.MoveNext
End If%>
</td>
<td>
<% If Trim(RS("Team")) = "OPS2" And not RS.EOF Then
Response.Write(RS("NumDocs")) 
RS.MoveNext 
End If%>
</td>
<td>
<% If Trim(RS("Team")) = "OPS3" And not RS.EOF Then
Response.Write(RS("NumDocs")) 
RS.MoveNext 
End If%>
</td>
<td>
<% If Trim(RS("Team")) = "OPS4" And not RS.EOF Then
Response.Write(RS("NumDocs")) 
RS.MoveNext 
End If%>
</td>
<td>
<% If Trim(RS("Team")) = "OPS5" And not RS.EOF Then
Response.Write(RS("NumDocs")) 
RS.MoveNext 
End If%>
</td>
<td>
<% If Trim(RS("Team")) = "OPS6" And not RS.EOF Then
Response.Write(RS("NumDocs")) 
RS.MoveNext 
End If%>
</td>
<td>
<% If Trim(RS("Team")) = "OPS7" And not RS.EOF Then
Response.Write(RS("NumDocs")) 
RS.MoveNext 
End If%>
</td>
<td>
<% If Trim(RS("Team")) = "OPS8" And Not RS.EOF Then
Response.Write(RS("NumDocs")) 
RS.MoveNext 
End If%>
</td>
<td>
<% If Trim(RS("Team")) = "OPS9" And Not RS.EOF Then
Response.Write(RS("NumDocs")) 
RS.MoveNext 
End If%>
</td>
```

The header row contains 10 hard coded headings, OPS1, OPS10, OPS2, etc.

The section above which populates OPS7's colum is fine, and the value of "2" is written to the cell. Then I get an error on the next column for OPS8 -  obviously there's no returned value for this as it only goes up to OPS7. This is why I put a Not EOF in the IF statement, but I am still getting the error.

Can anyone assist?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should move the RS.EOF to the first check in the IF statement E.G., go from this

```
If Trim(RS("Team")) = "OPS9" And Not RS.EOF Then
```

to this

```
If Not RS.EOF Then
    If Trim(RS("Team")) = "OPS9" Then
        ... logic here ...
    End If
End If
```

The problem is that `And` is not a short circuit operation in classic asp.

Comment: I think the problem is the RS.MoveNext that it hits after writing the NumDocs value for the last record. It does not like the fact that I am trying to MoveNext even though the next record does not exist?

Comment: @ben: Kane has the right idea but has failed to realise that VB logical expressions do not short cut.  When `Not RS.EOF` is false there will still be an attempt to read the field "Team" that will generate an error.

Comment: @Ben you have to write two if..then blocks: *If Not RS.EOF Then [new line] If Trim(RS("Team")) = "OPS9" Then...*

Comment: I thought about having a new IF within that same If but it didn't appear to work. So what I did was If RS.EOF = True Then Variable = "Nothing" ElseIf Trim(RS("Team")) = "OPS9" Then...and it seems to work. I thought perhaps like Unix it would expect some kind of statement before the next if. I will play around with the suggested solution above though of going straight from Then to another If again

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is no error message associated with this code.

80020009 = Accessing data of a recordset that is EOF